# How to use authorization in Gateway for a .NET microservice based app using Ocelot

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, ocelot

We have a .NET microservice based app where the Gateway is built using Ocelot. Until now we didn't do any authentication in the Gateway, the frontend calls an Authentication Provider service which responds with an JWT token, the token gets added to request headers and then, the new requests go through gateway and each particular microservice is concerned with authentication and authorization.

We also have API Key based authentication in place, but it's not used until now.

I added a new microservice with authentication done by API Key and I want to handle authorization in the Gateway. That means the gateway should check the claims based on JWT token and if claims matches forward the request to the microservice using an API key header.

How can I do it with Ocelot, instead of writing controllers and actions for each corresponding microservice controllers and actions? I thought about implementing Delegating Handlers to take care of it, but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

A clean way to do this, is to have the access token between the client and the API gateway and to then use the [token exchange flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693) between the gateway and the underlying APIs so as to keep a potential attack surface on the initial access token small and avoid exposing internal mechanics (e.g. multiple audiences of underlying APIs in your initial access token, multiple api scopes).

There are many sources of information about this online. [Here's one](https://www.scottbrady91.com/oauth/delegation-patterns-for-oauth-20) to get you started.